How do I update svn when using TortoiseSVN?
I've just installed TortoiseSVN v1.14.7, which is linked against the Subversion library 1.14.3. But when I do svn --version I get 1.6.6. Going to the Apache downloads page just links back to the TortoiseSVN downloads page.
To note : I'm trying to see why I get the error "This client is too old to work with working copy" when using svn log despite both client and server being on svn 1.6.6.
Running where svn indicates I have 2 installed:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\svn.exe
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe


Can you add the output of where svn to your question? It might be you're using an older version of Subversion CLI installed somewhere else.

Indeed it seems I have 2 installed :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\svn.exe
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe
Stupid problems, stupid stackoverflow questions :) Thanks !

Thanks for accepting my answer. Happened a lot at a former job where we had Cygwin and TortoiseSVN installed alongside.

It seems you have two different instances of Subversion CLI installed.
You have the following options to remedy the situation:

Uninstall the older version of Subversion.
Remove the directory where the wrong version of svn.exe resides from your PATH environment variable.
Make sure the newer version of svn.exe is found in PATH before the other one.

